# If one or more letters equals the same as a variable; Python

Tags: python

I have some code:

```
multi = "testtest"

if(type[0] == multi[0]):
    print("test")
```

But then if I run it, it works, but if I type t, the 1st letter, and then some other letters:
tfdsajfdsaf, it won't print test. Is there any other way I could make this work if the other letters are different?

Comment: what is `type` here? tyoe is a class and a built-in function, but you are trying to access it like a list.

Comment: What are you trying to test here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you might want to use startswith(), which is a part of the string class.

```
if string_name.startswith(multi[0]):
    print 'test'
```

You can also use slices:

```
if string_name.startswith(multi[:3]):
    print 'test'
```

Comment: Assuming `type` and `multi` are both strings, his current code will already do what you suggest. `string1[0] == string2[0]` is valid.